# Initializing the media player in flutter

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, flutter, media

I want to initialize media player in flutter(android) for playing audio file. Like in Android i used:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.audio);
            mPlayer.start();
```

So, like this how can i implement this thing in flutter. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: For Android https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_intent might be able to do that.

Comment: You can also take [a look at these plugins](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=player) to see if there is something that already works for you.